# Powershell CSV output - cant delete rows and special charaters

Tags: sql, powershell, csv

I'm having trouble with a `csv` file. My script is collecting data from a SQL Table, then it should write result as a `csv` file. My problem is that the `csv` file my code currently creates has speech marks and two rows of header that i don't want.

Right now my file looks like this:

> TYPE System.Data.DataRow
>
> code,"order","price"
>
> product1,"1","207,75"
>
> product2,"1","95,24"

I would like it to look like this:

> product1;1;207,7
>
> product2;1;95,24

My code:

```
$VAR1 = "select [product], [order], [price] from TABLE1
$VAR2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $VAR1 -serverinstance SERVER1
$Result | Export-Csv -path C:\test55.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `TYPE` header line by using the `-NoTypeInformation` switch on `Export-CSV`.

I don't think you can switch off the speech marks, but they are useful in case one of your data values includes a comma in it. If you open the CSV in Excel the speech marks won't be visible, so they are honoured by things that read CSV. If you wanted to remove them you could do a `-replace` to do so but it would risk removing them where they are part of the data.

If you want to remove the header line, you could use `ConvertTo-CSV` and then use `Select-Object` to skip the first line of the output.

So for example:

```
$VAR1 = "select [product], [order], [price] from TABLE1"
$VAR2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $VAR1 -serverinstance SERVER1

($Result | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Select-Object -Skip 1) -Replace '"' |
    Out-File C:\test55.csv
```

Comment: that worked like a charm. Thank You. I needed to remove speech marks because my program dont accept cav with them. Also, brace yourself, work automation incoming :)